# How do I display the namespace in Dokuwiki search results?

Tags: dokuwiki

When executing a search in the main dokuwiki site it displays the namespace a page is in, but I can't figure out how it is configured to do this - does anyone know?

Example search: https://www.dokuwiki.org/start?do=search&id=test

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing to do. It's the default behaviour. Did you maybe change the useheadings configuration? Then search results will show the page's first header instead of the page name (and namespace).

Comment: Ah. You are correct - we do have useheadings enabled. Is there any reason why it would not make sense to 'still include the namespace in search results but use the heading of the relevant start page', like indexmenu? Or is it just that no-one has written that functionality yet?